# How to use Custom table name for Quartz tables in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, quartz-scheduler, quart

I am using **quartz** with spring boot 2.x. Can I use **custom table names** and custom column names for the given quartz tables? I can prefix, but my requirement is to change the name of the table.

If yes, then how can I keep the sync.

Ex: instead of `qrtz_JOB_DETAILS` (`qrtz_` is prefixed here), can I create a table as `qrtz_myorg_jobDetails`?

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done out of the box.

All table names are in constants class in jdbcjobstore package
https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/Constants.html